# Injectivity of the Generalized Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am interested in the generalized Fourier transform of a measure $
\mu$ along a direction $\theta$, that is defined as follows:
$$
(\mathcal{F}_g (\mu))(s\theta) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-i \pi g(x,s\theta)} d\mu(x),
$$
where $s\in \mathbb{R}$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and the function $g$ represents the 'basis' of the transform. For instance, if $g(x,\theta) = x^\top \theta$, then we recover the classical Fourier transform.

My question is as follows: What are the required conditions for $g$ such that the resulting transform is injective?

I have tried to find references for finding the answer; however, I couldn't find any accessible reference. My current expectation is that $g$ should be homogeneous of order 1 in $\theta$.

Comment: Here you are asking about general integral transforms, you should restrict to a small concrete class of functions $g$. And start with the case $d = 1, d \mu(x) = \phi'(x)dx, \phi \in C^\infty_c$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Even in that case, I am not sure how to show the injectivity. Could you give me some references?